# Wordpress plugin for nicer looking slugs? Have multiple pages named the same but they get different slugs

Tags: php, seo, slug

This wordpress site I'm touching up has a page hierarchy which is responsible for the urls.

Basically the urls look like page1/subpage/subsubpage etc.

The problem is, this site is for a recurring competition and therefore the urls are like
2011/results
2012/results
2013/results

Which wordpress in turn makes 
2011/results
2012/results-1
2013/results-2

Which doesn't look that great..

Is it possible to mod_rewrite or something to work around this? I understand the need in Wordpress for unique slugs but I really can't see why they enforce it even when it's impossible to get duplicate urls for different pages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [Custom Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/) plugin for Wordpress.  With it, you can choose the permalink of each post/page individually.  It is great for situations like yours where you want to fine tune the URLs in some corner cases.